# Ubuntu 18.04 New Netplan / IP Configuration (pointopoint?)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, configuration, ifconfig

I have a Root-Server with `Proxmox` installed. Until now, I always had Ubuntu 16. Now i upgraded a VM to Ubuntu 18 and I need an example for the new `netplan` configuration.

This was my old interfaces file:

```
auto ens18
    iface ens18 inet static
    address 195.201.52.XXX
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    pointopoint 195.201.8.YYY
    gateway 195.201.8.YYY
    dns-nameservers 213.133.98.98 213.133.99.99 213.133.100.100 8.8.8.8
```

Because I couldn't find the option pointopoint with the new `netplan` I'm struggling to activate this VM. I know I could simply install `ifupdown` again. But if there is a possibility, I would like to keep the new `netplan`.

**Additional info:**
Have a look at my Configuration Files: https://pastebin.com/Havqfw7t

IPv4 Forwarding is enabled on both Guest and Host System.

Answer (score 7):

You have the right idea in your "additional info" pastebin. Applying the same IP addresses as your question:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [195.201.52.XXX/32]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 195.201.8.YYY
        on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [213.133.98.98,213.133.99.99,213.133.100.100,8.8.8.8]
```

However, you seem to have the same IP address on multiple interfaces in your host config; that might not help.

Basically, all your need for point-to-point is to add a static route to 0.0.0.0/0 via the IP of your peer; and make sure to set the route 'on-link: true'.

We put this up on the netplan.io website, too:
https://netplan.io/examples#directly-connected-gateway

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 18 on different hosts with proxmox. My netplan configuration inside vm and container as follows:

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:  
    ens18:  
      addresses: [ "192.168.1.18/32" ]  
      nameservers:  
        addresses: [ "1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1" ]  
      routes:  
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0  
          via: 192.168.1.1  
          on-link: true
```

192.168.1.18 is the ip of my container/vm
192.168.1.1 is the ip of my gateway
1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 are public dns server

[image]